# Naudio float Sample and Concentus.OggFile short Sample, convert mp3 to opus ogg

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio, ogg, opus

trying to convert mp3 file to opus ogg file by using

NAudio: https://github.com/naudio/NAudio

Concentus.OggFile https://github.com/lostromb/concentus.oggfile

```
using (var source = new MemoryStream(mp3File))
using (var mp3Reader = new MyAudioFileReader(source, FileReaderType.Mp3))
using (var memo = new MemoryStream())
{
    var bufferFloat = new float[mp3Reader.Length / (mp3Reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8)];
    var count = mp3Reader.Read(bufferFloat, 0, bufferFloat.Length);

    //convert float to short 
    var buffShort = new short[count];
    var scale = (float)(short.MaxValue);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        buffShort[i] = (short)(bufferFloat[i] * scale);
    }
    //encoder
    var encoder = OpusEncoder.Create(48000, 
        mp3Reader.WaveFormat.Channels, 
        OpusApplication.OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO);

    encoder.Bitrate = 65536;//64kbps

    //tags
    var tags = new OpusTags();
    tags.Fields[OpusTagName.Title] = "Title";
    tags.Fields[OpusTagName.Artist] = "Artist";

    //
    var oggOut = new OpusOggWriteStream(encoder, memo, tags);

    oggOut.WriteSamples(buffShort, 0, buffShort.Length);
    oggOut.Finish();

    result = memo.ToArray();
}
```

I don't know the basics, did some GDD and here is result of what I get.

> OpusOggWriteStream.WriteSamples()

requires short[] sample as input.
is it okay the way I convert the NAudio float[] sample provider to short[] ?

probably not cuz output file can't be played .

this code doesn't work and I have no idea why :"D

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too little too late but whatever. As far as I can tell your code looks fine, so to debug I would try just a few things:

1. There is actually a WriteSamples() overload in OggOpusWriteStream that accepts float[]. Try using that first
2. I would make sure that mp3Reader.Read actually produces as much data as you believe it to be. I wonder if it might only be returning a single frame of decoded data or something like that. Try writing out the data as uncompressed pcm and sanity checking it

I checked to see if there was some bug in Concentus.Oggfile since you only ever WriteSamples() once - I thought maybe it wouldn't finalize the pages properly in that case, but I can't find anything.